# Ionic Deploy: plugin is not installed or has not loaded

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am new to `Ionic`, I am trying to run an ionic project that my co-worker has started, using a web browser for development purposes. I keep seeing this line appear in my browser's console:

```
Ionic Deploy: plugin is not installed or has not loaded. Have you run `ionic plugin 
  add ionic-plugin-deploy` yet?
```

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Are you trying to run ionic project on Web Browser ?

Comment: Which command are you running?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Yes, I am running it in web browser.
@ItaloAyres I am using `ionic serve`